# Assignment method created using define_singleton_method returns the wrong value

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, immutability

## Background

The Entity class is a base class that gets inherited by several subclasses that holds entities received over a REST API. The entity classes are immutable and should return a new instance of themselves whenever a change is attempted.

The Entity class has an `.update()` method that takes a hash of values to update, if the changes aren't really changes it returns itself and if there are real changes it returns a new instance of itself with the changes effected before instantiation.

To be user friendly Entity also allows for direct assignment to properties (so that if a subclass of Entity has a name attribute you can do `instance.name = 'New Name'`) that also returns a new instance of the class. This is implemented in terms of update using dynamic methods that are created when the class is instantiated.

And they are the problem.

## Problem

The code in the Entity class looks, in part, like this (for a complete code listing and tests check out the Github repo: https://github.com/my-codeworks/fortnox-api.git):

```
require "virtus"
require "ice_nine"

class Entity

  extend Forwardable
  include Virtus.model

  def initialize( hash = {} )
    super
    create_attribute_setter_methods
    IceNine.deep_freeze( self )
  end

  def update( hash )
    attributes = self.to_hash.merge( hash )
    return self if attributes == self.to_hash
    self.class.new( attributes )
  end

private

  def create_attribute_setter_methods
    attribute_set.each do |attribute|
      name = attribute.options[ :name ]

      create_attribute_setter_method( name )
    end
  end

  def create_attribute_setter_method( name )
    self.define_singleton_method "#{name}=" do | value |
      self.update( name => value )
    end
  end

end
```

Doing this:

```
instance.update( name: 'New Name' )
```

and this:

```
instance.name = 'New Name'
```

Should be the same, literally since one is implemented in terms of the other.

While `.update()` works perfectly the `.attr=()` methods return the value you assign.

So in the above example `.update()` returns a new instance of the Entity subclass but `.attr=()` returns `'New Name'` ...

I have tries capturing the output inside the `.attr=()` method and log it before returning so that I have this:

```
self.define_singleton_method "#{name}=" do | value |
  p "Called as :#{name}=, redirecting to update( #{name}: #{value} )"
  r = self.update( name => value )
  p "Got #{r} back from update"
  return r
end
```

And the log lines say:

```
 "Called as :name=, redirecting to update( name: 'New Name' )"
 "Got #<TestEntity:0x007ffedbd0ad18> back from update"
```

But all I get is the string `'New Name'`...

My forehead is bloody and no posts I find show anything close to this. I bet I'm doing something wrong but I can't find it.

## Getting dirty

The Github repo has tests in rspec that you can run, the failing ones are focused right now and some extra logging is in the Entity class to capture the different internal steps.

Comments, links and/or pull requests are welcome.

Comment: Why does it say `string` in the log in place of `name`?

Comment: @Humza My specs uses different names than I used here. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the `=` methods always return the value being assigned.

```
o = Struct.new(:key).new(1)
o.define_singleton_method("something") { @something }
o.define_singleton_method("something=") do |v|
  @something = v
  return 6
end
```

As you can see, I've 'fixed' the return value to `6` each time `something=` is called. Let's see if it works:

```
o.something = 1 #=> outputs 1, not 6
o.something #=> outputs 1, so the method did indeed run
```

Conclusion? My guess is that an `=` method will return the value that you are assigning through it. And IMO it's better this way; one reason would be to ensure proper functioning of assignment chains:

```
new_val = o.something = some_val
```

Comment: Ok, and from how it looks to me this is a language feature? Hence no way to override (even if I agree that that would probably be a bad idéa :)).

Comment: TBH I haven't looked into it thoroughly enough to claim it to be a Ruby feature; but it does seem that way. I was trying to implement what you want through `method_missing` within `o.instance_eval` but it was yielding the same results.

Comment: Yeah I went down that road first but it had some other problems as well. I looked it up, it's a language feature so no chance of an override. Thank you for the quick answer :)